# OpenCL: conversion from ' float* ' to ' cl_mem '

Tags: c++, opencl, caffe

In caffe source code (branch opencl),  sometimes I can see some like these(eg. in      src/caffe/layers/base_conv_layer.cpp line 400):

```
void func(cl_mem a, ...)
{...}

void func2(float* a, ...)
{
    ...
    func( (cl_mem) a, ...);
    ...
}
```

I think it is really strange, so I googled it, but got nothing about it.

Then I wrote a simple test code to figure out what happened, but I found this conversion is meaningless:

```
std::cout << long((void*)a) << " " << long((void*)(cl_mem(a))) << std::endl;
```

Their value is same !

So my question is why this conversion raises no problem in caffe opencl ?
What happened in this conversion ?

Comment: `(cl_mem) a` is a cast, not a conversion.

Comment: @simpel01 Thanks for comment! So, actually this cast does nothing special, and data in memory doesn't change. But why this cast worked in caffe opencl? As I know, cl_mem and float* are pretty different. Is there any trick to make it work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into class `SyncedMemory` (in `include/caffe/syncedmem.hpp` and `src/caffe/syncedmem.cpp`), you will find that a memory buffer is first created by `clCreateBuffer` and the handle is stored as a `cl_mem` object. The handle is then cast to type `DType*` when `gpu_data()` or `mutable_gpu_data()` is called. It can therefore be cast back to type `cl_mem` because it is a `cl_mem` object in the first place.